# Pagination with bootstrap and Angular4 on div / table

Tags: angular, pagination, bootstrap-4

I have a list of "cards" on an Angular4 project, and i want to display only 6 per page, i can use pagination on the table, but with "cards" i can't ( i think it's waiting for rows ans columns, the code of the cards is:

```
<div style="position:relative;">
                 <table class="row">
                    <div id="jasmine_content" class="x_content col-lg-4 col-md-5 col-sm-8 col-form-label-sm" [ngbCollapse]="isCollapsed"  *ngFor="let instance of entityList.list; trackBy:trackByFn; let idx=index;">
                        <div class="card mb-2 ">
                            <div class=" card-header table table-hover table-striped">

                                <td>

                                    <ng-container *ngFor="let column of entityList.metadata.columns" [ngSwitch]="column.order" >

                                        <tr *ngSwitchCase="2" >{{ entityName.toLowerCase() + '.' + column.key  | translate}}&nbsp; - &nbsp;
                                            {{getValue(instance, column.key) | ellipsis:200}}</tr>
                                        <tr *ngSwitchCase="3" >{{ entityName.toLowerCase() + '.' + column.key  | translate}}&nbsp; - &nbsp;
                                            {{getValue(instance, column.key) | ellipsis:200}}</tr>
                                        <tr *ngSwitchCase="5" >{{ entityName.toLowerCase() + '.' + column.key  | translate}}&nbsp; - &nbsp;
                                            {{getValue(instance, column.key) | ellipsis:200}}</tr>

                                    </ng-container>
                                </td>
                               </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </table>
</div>
```

and i got the cards, but only on one single page, how can i use pagination in simplyest way ?

PS: On the list i use teh next line to paginate:

```
...
<table datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger" class="table table-hover table-striped">
<thead>
                <tr>
                    <th *ngFor="let column of entityList.metadata.columns">
                        {{ entityName.toLowerCase() + '.' + column.key | translate}}
                    </th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let instance of entityList.list; trackBy:trackByFn; let idx=index;">
                    <ng-container *ngFor="let column of entityList.metadata.columns"  [ngSwitch]="column.type">
                        <td *ngSwitchCase="'date'">{{getValue(instance, column.key) | date:'y/MM/dd'}}</td>
                        <td *ngSwitchCase="'text'">{{getValue(instance, column.key) | ellipsis:200}}</td>
                        <td *ngSwitchCase="'boolean'">
                            <input type="checkbox" [checked]="getValue(instance, column.key)" disabled/></td>
                        <td *ngSwitchDefault>{{ getValue(instance, column.key)}}</td>
                    </ng-container>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

...
```

And i got pagination with lines lines and columns on table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i made it, i've uses ngx-paginantion:
First of all install it:

```
npm install ngx-pagination
```

add it on appModule:

```
import { NgxPaginationModule } from 'ngx-pagination';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        NgxPaginationModule
....
```

on Html, *ngfor you want ot iterato and subdivide into pages :

```
*ngFor="let instance of (entityList.list | paginate: { itemsPerPage:5, currentPage: p} )

(...)

<pagination-controls (pageChange)="p = $event"></pagination-controls>
```

---

> to make things easy, i am creating cards by that div:
>
> ```
> <table class="row">
> <div  id="jasmine_content" class="x_content col-lg-4 col-md-5 col-sm-8 col-form-label-sm" [ngbCollapse]="isCollapsed"  *ngFor="let
> ```
>
> instance of (entityList.list | searchFilter: search.value );
>   trackBy:trackerByFn; let idx=index;">
>       (.......cards here......)
>
> how can i paginate that items (instance) using ngb-pagination, or
>   something like that?